# Show that the function $u(x)=\arctan(\frac{1}{x})$ is in $L^p(0,+\infty)$ $ \ \forall p>1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I need to show that $||u(x)||_{L^p}$ is finite.
$$||u(x)||_{L^p}^p=\int_0^{+\infty}|u(x)|^pdx=\int_0^{+\infty}|\arctan\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)|^pdx=\int_0^{+\infty}\arctan^p\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)dx$$
At this point I thought a substitution: $t=\frac{1}{x}$, so $dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt$ and the integral become 
$$-\int_{+\infty}^0\bigg(\frac{\arctan(t)}{t^2}\bigg)^pdt=\int_0^{+\infty}\bigg(\frac{\arctan(t)}{t^2}\bigg)^pdt\le\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)^p\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^2}=\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)^p\bigg[-\frac{1}{t}\bigg]_0^{+\infty}$$
but it diverges, I can't understand how to bound above this thing. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\text{arctan}^p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{1}{x^p}
$$
and the function $\displaystyle x \mapsto \frac{1}{x^p}$ is integrable on $\left[1,+\infty\right[$. Then
$$
\text{arctan}^p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \underset{(0^{+})}{\sim}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^p
$$
So $\displaystyle x \mapsto \text{arctan}^p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is continuous on $\left[0,1\right]$, so it is integrable on $\left]0,1\right]$. 
Hence it is integrable on $\left]0,+\infty\right[$.

Comment: It might be better to start with $\arctan u \sim u$ for small positive $u$ which translates to $\arctan (1/x) \sim 1/x$ for large $x$ and then on to what you said.

Comment: But i precised it was around infinity

Comment: In a easy way, I use the fact that $\arctan^p(\frac{1}{x})\sim(\frac{\pi}{2})^p$ on $[0,1]$, and then I use the fact that $\arctan^p\bigg({\frac{1}{x}}\sim\frac{1}{x^p}\bigg)$ on $[1,+\infty]$. Then I think I can divide the integral in $$\int_0^1\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)^pdx+\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}dx$$
Right?

Comment: That s it. That s why i have done